# jQuery Chosen Multiple Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-chosen

is it possible to set the different background-color of selected values in the chosen plugin?
Color should be given depends on class or attr etc.
The image shows what has to be achieved.[image]

Comment: Yes. Share the plugin's code / jsfiddle.

Comment: @OfirBaruch http://jsfiddle.net/PrHDH/260/

Comment: hope there is a solution:)

Comment: so far templating feature is not supported in chosen js, but its available with select2 js. please try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen();

$(".chosen-select").on('change', function (event,el) {
  var selected_element = $(".chosen-select option:contains("+el.selected+")");
  var selected_value  = selected_element.val();
  var parent_optgroup = selected_element.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
  var parent_optgroup_class = selected_element.closest('optgroup').attr('class');
  $(".search-choice:last > span").css("background-color", parent_optgroup_class);
  selected_element.text(parent_optgroup+' - '+selected_value);
  
  //$(selected_element).addClass(`${parent_optgroup_class}`);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<select multiple data-placeholder="example" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" tabindex="5">
  <option value=""></option>
  <optgroup label="NFC EAST" class="red">
    <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
    <option>New York Giants</option>
    <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
    <option>Washington Redskins</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="NFC NORTH" class="blue">
    <option>Chicago Bears</option>
    <option>Detroit Lions</option>
    <option>Green Bay Packers</option>
    <option>Minnesota Vikings</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="NFC SOUTH" class="green">
    <option>Atlanta Falcons</option>
    <option>Carolina Panthers</option>
    <option>New Orleans Saints</option>
    <option>Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

I have removed the trigger event from **selected_element.text** and add class to the outgroup.
Just add the color name to the class it will automatically set as a background color.